# Multi-threading with Informix and the IBM CSDK

Tags: c++, multithreading, informix

I am working with Informix in C++ with the IBM CSDK client libraries. I use the multi-threaded version of the libraries and each thread uses its own ITConnection object. 
Still the application crashes if more than one thread is spawned. 
Has anybody come across a similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this issue (for Solaris OS). Need to link multidreading versions of libraries. They are named as follows libth* instead of libif*.

Answer (score 0):

More questions than an answer...

Please identify which platform (operating system and version, and hardware type if it might be needed) and which version of CSDK?  (Standard rules for many product-related questions.)

What compilation options did you use on your C++ code?  What was the link line you used?  Do you have support for the product?  (If you do, contact IBM Technical Support.)  Do you have a stack backtrace for the problem?

No, I've not seen that problem, but I've not pushed the multi-threaded version of the code very hard - or, for most purposes, at all.

*(Since you're new, please add the extra information by editing your question, rather than by adding an 'answer'.  Only add an answer if you cannot edit the question.)*